# AngularJS $apply or $digest

Tags: angularjs

I am using Angular JS in my asp.net web forms application. I know that web forms and Angular JS dont make a good pair.

I have an update panel where it does partial postbacks. After every postback I have to compile the angular to make it work.

So I have added the below code in my page.

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(function (sender, args) {
    var elem = angular.element($('[ng-controller]'));
    elem.replaceWith($compile(elem)($scope));
    $scope.$digest();                       
});
```

I have couple of questions here:
1. Is this ok to compile `ng-controller` bit or should I do a full `$compile` on the `ng-app`.
2. For  Every postback there are some orphaned scopes. How can I remove them? Or Is it ok If I leave them as is. Doesn't it cause a memory leak.
3. Which one is preferable `$digest` or `$apply` and why?

Comment: [$digest vs $apply](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/)